# Play audio file of a system directory

Tags: apache, php-5.3

I have a apache server its locate on /var/www/html.
But i want play a audio file on the browser that is locate on /var/spool/monitor/file.wav

I'm trying to do directly and dont work, clearly:

```
 <audio controls>
  <source src="/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2016/09/07/internal-2000-2001-20160907-115123-1473259882.329.wav" type="audio/wav">

Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

How can i do that?
I'm using PHP5.3 (Yii1.1) and apache server

Comment: You need to learn how a document root works. Anything outside of a site's document root is by definition UNREACHABLE by clients. That's a Good Thing (tm). If you make your root directory (`/`) your document root, then by definition your ENTIRE FILESYSTEM is visible to the web. So `/var` is not reachable, unless you set up an alias or symlink with the webserver and/or document root to "fake out" the webserver into thinking it's within the root.

Comment: The file needs to be accessible from the browser. Either copy it to /var/www/html, add the other directory to your public directories in the HTTP server config, or ship the file using a PHP wrapper. Or simply put the audio file somewhere else on the web or another server.

Comment: Ok... i solve it with a symbolic link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="your path" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
```

path should be accessible from browser ex : http://10.10.10.10/your-folder/file.mp3

this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this making a symbolic link with the command terminal on the server path (/var/www/html):

```
ln -s /var/spool/asterisk/monitor name_of_link
```

Thanks